# Raspberry Pi would not start

Tags: pi-3, boot, sd-card

[image]

Hi, when booting Rasberry PI I get following error messages and RPI does not start. I have took out SD Card, run chkdsk on Windows machine, did not detect errors. Is there anything I can do to fix it? Alternatively copy files to another SD card?

Comment: You should try to boot your Pi from another SD card. If it boots successfully from this other SD card, then you can conclude that the first one is corrupted. Corrupted does not mean that no files can be recovered, but any recovery of files from your current SD card will have to be done on a Linux machine that can mount an `ext4` filesystem.

Comment: *"run chkdsk on Windows machine"* -> This won't detect problems with the root filesystem, which is 95%+ of the card.  However, I don't think this is a corruption issue, it is a legitimate hardware problem -- either the card is defunct, the SD card reader is damaged, or the Pi and the card are incompatible, which is rare but can happen.  You haven't actually said if the card ever worked, or if this is a new Pi and card etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are two partitions on the SD card.

A small boot partition formatted in FAT32 which is visible to Windows.

The rest of the SD card is formatted as EXT4 and is not visible to Windows.

chkdsk will only have checked the small boot partition.

You need to mount the SD card in another Linux machine to see if any EXT4 files are recoverable.  Perhaps boot Linux on your Windows machine with a "live" disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the SD Card in the Pi and boot it will check the partitions if an error is detected.

You can force it to check by adding `fsck.mode=force` to `cmdline.txt` in the boot partition.

chkdsk is unlikely to fix the problem. You need to restore from your backup.